# How to get access to the ToolTip component of a Form by code

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, tooltip

I am struggling with a very tricky thing. I know there must be a solution, but I need your help.

I am working on a form translation (Multi-language) class (dll). You can instantiate the class and set a language. Then, this class enumerates all the Form controls and writes an XML file with all the strings. So far, all fine.

Now the trick: If there is a ToolTip component added to the form, I want to access the control ToolTips as well, but I did not find a way to get access to the ToolTip component by code.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The ToolTip does not inherit `Control` but only `Component`. Therefore it is not contained in the `Form.Controls`-Collection. You could iterate over the `Form.components.Components` to get the ToolTips.

Comment: or get all of them via LINQ: `List<ToolTip> ToolTipList =  this.components.Components.OfType<ToolTip>().ToList();`

Comment: Hi Mong Zhu, how to get access to "compontents" outside the designer of a form?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by sudden.
Here it is:

```
    private static void GetAllToolTips(Form frm)
    {

        Type typeForm = frm.GetType();
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeForm.GetField("components", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        IContainer parent = (IContainer)fieldInfo.GetValue(frm);
        List<ToolTip> ToolTipList = parent.Components.OfType<ToolTip>().ToList();

        if (ToolTipList.Count > 0)
        {
            ToolTip tt = ToolTipList[0];
            foreach (Control c in frm.Controls)
            {
                string text = tt.GetToolTip(c);

            }
        }

    }
```

**Thanks for helping**

Answer (score 0):

```
  ToolTip1.GetToolTip(your_control)
```